# Postcode.tech Authorization not working for some reason

Tags: php

I've been making a couple of attempts now to make this dutch postcode.tech api getting to work through an CURLOPT but nothing seem to make it work.

The code is as following:

```
    <?php
$headers = array(
    'Bearer: f87d5d41-2495-47bf-8646-7fa1c46512e8'
);
echo $headers;
//The URL that we want to GET.
$url = 'https://postcode.tech/api/v1/postcode/full?postcode=1111XX&number=123';

//Initialize cURL.
$ch = curl_init();
 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
//Set the URL that you want to GET by using the CURLOPT_URL option.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://postcode.tech/api/v1/postcode/full?postcode=1446WJ&number=88');
 
//Set CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER so that the content is returned as a variable.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 
//Set CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION to true to follow redirects.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
 
//Execute the request.
$data = curl_exec($ch);
 
//Close the cURL handle.
curl_close($ch);
 
//Print the data out onto the page.
echo $data;
?>
```

I keep getting { "message": "Unauthorized" } when I am trying but the headers / key is correctly as it should be.

Comment: You might consider not exposing your API key...

Comment: use postman or similar tool to debug any http requests. After trying the request with your authorization token... :-) ... I get the same unauthorized error. Seems like your bearer token is invalid or the API is faulty.

Answer (score 0):

Valid syntax for an authorization header:

`Authorization: <type> <credentials>`

So, change:

`$headers = array( 'Bearer: f87d5d41-2495-47bf-8646-7fa1c46512e8' );`

to:

`$headers = array("Authorization: Bearer f87d5d41-2495-47bf-8646-7fa1c46512e8");`

Output:

```
{"postcode":"1446WJ","number":88,"street":"Volume","city":"Purmerend","municipality":"Purmerend","province":"Noord-Holland","geo":{"lat":52.509485977219,"lon":5.0036936976488}}
```

Some background on authorization header [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization)

Comment: The header syntax was wrong indeed, thanks for your reply I had fixed it.